# OBIEE 10G outer join

Tags: obiee

I am new to OBIEE 10G.

I have a DimA (dimension), FactA (fact). I mapped foreign key relationship between DimA and FactA on DimA.A = FactA.A in BMM, the relationship is inner and greyed out, so I can't change it to outer join.

So in the answers report, it only shows data of the inner join of the two tables. What I want is to show all items in DimA and related items of FactA or 0 for those not related.

I have posted a similar question here before https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2596618
But I still can't modify the relationship (still greyed out) even if I opened a offline repository.

And what I am thinking is is there an option in answers to dynamically control the join (inner or outer). For example, sometimes I want to show only matched DimA and FactA , sometimes all DimA and related FactA or 0, so that I don't have to modify the BMM in repository every time if the requirement changes.

What's the best practice for this case?

Thanks.

--update

I found in physical diagram, I can't change the type of relationship (complex join or foreign key). But in logical diagram I can change for both.

I found these useful:
http://everythingoracle.com/obieeldd.htm
http://obinsight.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/understanding-complex-join-and-physical.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're in OBIEE 10g, you can use a complex join. in a complex join, you can modify the join type.